# Can't access JSON returned from Spring REST service

Tags: javascript, json, spring, rest

I'm calling a Spring REST service and getting the following JSON back and store it in a variable:

```
{  
  "srSearchDetail":{  
     "srSearchSummary":[  
        {  
           "accountNumber":"12",
           "accountType":null
        }
     ],
     "rowsInAPage":1
  }
}
```

I want to access the `srSearchSummary` array, but accessing `jsonVariable.srSearchDetail.srSearchSummary` tells me that `srSearchDetail` is undefined.  I then `console.log()`'d `Object.keys(jsonVariable)` and got an array with 480 values, all following this pattern:

0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", ... 480: "480"

[image]

What gives?  How do I access the data I want?

Comment: What is the result of console.log(jsonVariable)? Looks to me like you are getting an array back, not a simple object as expected.

Comment: the object you got the keys to is the string response, which is acting like an array of chars. do `jsonVariable = JSON.parse(jsonVariable);` and then try it. (the response need to be converted from a string to an actual json object before you can use it like that.)

Comment: @Pamblam that was it, thank you.